# Can LOCC operations take product states to non-product states?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-operation, locc-operation

Given a product state $\rho^{(1)} \otimes \rho^{(2)}$, can this state become non-product state under LOCC? Can LOCC create correlations between two systems?

Comment: I'd remember that non-product states can be correlated. Absence of entanglement doesn't mean absence of correlations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, the classical communication allows you to generate the necessary correlations between two sites. For instance, suppose that Alice flips a coin and communicates the outcome to Bob. When the outcome is heads, they use their local operations to create the state $|0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0 |$. When the outcome is tails they use their local operations to create $|1\rangle \langle 1 | \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1|$. Overall the state they generate (assuming the coin is fair) is
$$
\frac12 |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes |0 \rangle \langle 0 |+ \frac12 |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1 |
$$
which is not a product state. You can make this construction more general and create any separable state in this manner.

Comment: Does this mean LOCC can create entanglement from separable state?

Comment: No. LOCC operations cannot *create* entanglement. Correlated systems are not necessarily entangled (non-separable).

Comment: Extending the above construction would allow you to create any probabilistic mixture of product states, i.e., any separable state.